# Changing multiple Target Paths for multiple Reference Components

Tags: reference, path, target, aem

I need to change the target path for each reference component in a page and have been doing it manually. There are about 1000 of these and it's taking forever. Is there a way to replace a certain part of all the Target Paths at once? Essentially, I just need to replace a part in the string i.e. "/us_ck" with "ca_ck."

Comment: yes it can be done. But what have you tried till now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Bulk Editor](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/bulk_editor.html), if you turn on the import feature for it. You could also use the [CQ Groovy Console](https://github.com/Citytechinc/cq-groovy-console), and write a Groovy script that makes that change for you. This is probably the better way to go.